# Where are the colors recognized by hyperref package by default defined?

Tags: hyperref, color

I can use code like this in my preamble without importing the `xcolor` package:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=magenta,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

I want to know where these colors `magenta` and `blue` are defined.

I checked http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf but there is no occurrence of the word `blue` in this documentation.

Where can I find the comprehensive list of colors supported by `hyperref` by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With option colorlinks, hyperref will load the color package, and you will get the colors predefined by this package which is a rather small set:

black, white, red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to the question you asked is: [in the package `hycolor`.](https://ctan.org/pkg/hycolor?lang=en)

The [pragmatic answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean/2450) is: if you need color names, `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}`.  As of 2020, you can load it either before or after `hyperref`.  This gives you all the standard color names from HTML/CSS/SVG (camel-case and remove spaces, such as `SkyBlue`).  You can look up how to get more colors than that in [the manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf)